# Fan control on Lenovo Thinkpad Edge S430 and Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: thinkpad, fan

I'm trying to make my thinkpad's fan run on higher speeds because of overheating. I've enabled `fan_control` in `thinkpad-acpi` module, at least I think so:

```
$ cat /sys/module/thinkpad_acpi/parameters/fan_control 
Y
```

However, it does not seem to respond to changes:

```
$ echo 'level 7' > /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
```

No error, but no reaction either. Any advice on how to proceed? Does it mean my Thinkpad does not support fan control?

Note that this question is NOT the same as [that one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82246/how-to-control-thinkpad-acpi-via-procfs-rhel-6-4) - my `fan_control` is apparently on, and I do not get any `invalid argument` error when I'm trying to `echo` new level.

Comment: I'm having this issue now as well. Thinkpad t420. Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.